# Another way to say “when we send you there”

Tags: phrases

I’m looking for another way to say ..

> When we send you there

It’s referencing an introduction in a website context; When you click the link we will let the destination know that you’re with us. Think of it like an introduction.

Comment: Is the triggering event the clicking of the link or the destination site acknowledging the clicker's "arrival"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Direct', 'redirect', 'forward', 'route' can all be made to work in place of send.

Specifically in the context of an introduction 'connect' may also be considered

If the *purpose* of the introduction is to suggest or recommend one party to the other, 'refer' probably best conveys that.